# Loading multiple png images in html5 canvas

Tags: html, image, canvas

I have seen quite a few code snippets and tutorials on how to load a single image and then draw that image but also draw shapes and such on the image, but is there a way to load multiple images (pngs) with transparent sections on to canvas so you can layer them and then download the composite?

Brian

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of an image preloader that will wait until all the images are fully loaded and then call the `start()` function:

```
// image preloader

// canvas related variables
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

// put the paths to your images in imageURLs[]
var imageURLs=[];  
imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/face1.png");
imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/face2.png");

// the loaded images will be placed in imgs[]
var imgs=[];
var imagesOK=0;
startLoadingAllImages(imagesAreNowLoaded);

// Create a new Image() for each item in imageURLs[]
// When all images are loaded, run the callback (==imagesAreNowLoaded)
function startLoadingAllImages(callback){

  // iterate through the imageURLs array and create new images for each
  for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
    // create a new image an push it into the imgs[] array
    var img = new Image();
    // Important! By pushing (saving) this img into imgs[],
    //     we make sure the img variable is free to
    //     take on the next value in the loop.
    imgs.push(img);
    // when this image loads, call this img.onload
    img.onload = function(){ 
      // this img loaded, increment the image counter
      imagesOK++; 
      // if we've loaded all images, call the callback
      if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
        callback();
      }
    };
    // notify if there's an error
    img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
    // set img properties
    img.src = imageURLs[i];
  }      
}

// All the images are now loaded
// Do drawImage & fillText
function imagesAreNowLoaded(){

  // the imgs[] array now holds fully loaded images
  // the imgs[] are in the same order as imageURLs[]

  ctx.font="30px sans-serif";
  ctx.fillStyle="#333333";

  // drawImage the first image (face1.png) from imgs[0]
  // and fillText its label below the image
  ctx.drawImage(imgs[0],0,10);
  ctx.fillText("face1.png", 0, 135);

  // drawImage the first image (face2.png) from imgs[1]
  // and fillText its label below the image
  ctx.drawImage(imgs[1],200,10);
  ctx.fillText("face2.png", 210, 135);

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use a `for loop` to go thought each `image` object and then render that instead of duplicating code? Also shouldn't you have a `class` which would hold the image position aswell? the OP may want to move the images around the canvas.

Comment: @Canvas Sigh...please review the code. There is indeed a for-loop that creates, sources, loads and saves each image object -- there's no duplicate code. You could create a class if you desire, but (IMO) a class is overkill since the code is dead-simple (and often used just once at the beginning of the app). After they are loaded, all images are available anytime in the code via the `imgs[]` array.