# Using an Image as as Fill in JS instead of Color (Without Displaying it Upon Load)

Tags: javascript

I'm building a brick-breaker type game in JavaScript where I want to use images as a fill instead of colors, and the only info I can find about how to do that involves displaying the image first, and then using it in a JS method call, which is not what I want to do. Basically, I want all of the images I choose to display as 'bricks' upon page load. Here is my working code for colors. Just want to replace it with images. Thanks!

```
function drawBricks() {
for(c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
    for(r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
        if(bricks[c][r].status == 1) {       
            var brickX = (c*(brickWidth+brickPadding))+brickOffsetLeft;
            var brickY = (r*(brickHeight+brickPadding))+brickOffsetTop;
            bricks[c][r].x = brickX;
            bricks[c][r].y = brickY;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(brickX, brickY, brickWidth, brickHeight);
            ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33596638/loading-multiple-png-images-in-html5-canvas/33601666#33601666